# REGEX RE2 extract in Google Data Studio - REGEX_EXTRACT

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I am trying to extract the following string using Google Data Studio calculated fields, but **can´t find the proper RegEx syntax, due to the RE2 limitation.**

Can someone help with creation of 4 RegEx matches for this test string, which is separated by `/`, I need to separately match each part of the string.

All the content between separators is dynamic but the separators stays like you see.

Can't wrap my head around it, actually I **don't know if its even possible in RE2 in Google Data Studio.**

**Test string:**

> Group & Name/Group 2 & Name 2/Group 3 & Name 3/Group 4
>
> test string can also have only 3 parts
>
> Group & Name/Group 2 & Name 2/Group 3 & Name 3

**Expected result:**

I need 4 matching patterns for each part of the string separated by `/`

- 1 RegEx matching: Group & Name
- 2 RegEx matching: Group 2 & Name 2
- 3 RegEx matching: Group 3 & Name 3
- 4 RegEx matching: Group 4

I am stuck with this pattern, which only matches the 2nd group but I can't get the dynamic into it:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT( dimension , '\\\/([^\\\/]*)\\\/' )
```

**PS:** found out that `/` needs to be preceded by double `\\` otherwise you get "`Could not parse the formula`". In https://regex101.com/ it doesn't work with double `\\`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can only extract one thing at a time.  So, do you want 4 different patterns?

Comment: yes @TimBiegeleisen, thats the case, only one exctract can be done at once, thats the reason for 4 separate patterns to match, thanks for your interest

Comment: So again, are you asking for 4 patterns here?

Comment: yes, i need to extract the parts separately to different columns so even if one pattern would work for all it doenst help me @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Why not split on `/`?

Comment: @Toto do you have some example, I am beginer in the field of regex, thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

Try these four calls to `REGEXP_EXTRACT` for the first through fourth terms in your path:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(dimension, '^([^/]+)/')
REGEXP_EXTRACT(dimension, '^[^/]+/([^/]+)/')
REGEXP_EXTRACT(dimension, '^[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)')
REGEXP_EXTRACT(dimension, '^[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)')
```

Comment: thanks, it works ok with the 4 part string Group & Name/Group 2 & Name 2/Group 3 & Name 3/Group 4 but when it has only 3 parts its recording nulls Group & Name/Group 2 & Name 2/Group 3 & Name 3 from the second pattern, do you think it can be made dynamic to work with 2 - 4 string length?